# React-Router Router.HistoryLocation refreshes the page

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I am working on React-Express-Node application and focussing on SPA. I am using the react-router.

My server.js file looks like this (only routing part):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    Router.run(routes,function(Handler, state) {
        var ele = React.createElement(Handler);
        res.render(path.join(__dirname +  '/public/index'), {html: html});
    });

    next();

});
```

And the routes file has this code (pasting the main part):

```
module.exports = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={Main}>
        <Route name="about" path="about" handler={About}/>
        <Route name="about/id" path="about/:id" handler={About}/>
        <DefaultRoute name="default" handler={Home} />
    </Route>
);
```

And client.js looks like this:

```
Router.run(routes, function(Root,state){
    React.render(<Root />,document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

This setup works fine without any problem.

Now, I want to use the History API pushstate so that i can have better urls and get rid of #. To do that, I added `Router.HistoryLocation` as the second parameter in client.js and it works, it removes the # and gives clean urls. But however, my page refreshes which I don't want.

I have searched this all over and found couple of solutions but they are either using Flux or a custom router. I am surely missing something related to state but not able to figure out. Can someone point me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible to use `Router.HistoryLocation` with express server rendered SPA app (I'm doing it now).

You need to tell the server.js file where to get the history, i.e. `req.url`... like this.

```
Router.run(routes, req.url, function(Handler, state) {
    var ele = React.createElement(Handler);
    res.render(path.join(__dirname +  '/public/index'), {html: html});
});
```

If the server is set up correctly, the next item to check is how you're transitioning to the routes. Using a traditional anchor `<a/>` tag will always refresh the page. React Router has provided their own `<Link/>` component that allows you to navigate to your routes without causing a page reload. You can also look into calling `transitionTo()` directly on your router to cause a navigation as well.

Also, when a `<Link/>` tag is active it will also pass an active class to the tag so css can style it accordingly.

**Link**

```
<Link to="route" props={} query={}>My Link</Link>
```

**Navigation**

```
router.transitionTo('route', params, query);
```

Check out the [Link Docs](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Link) and [Navigation Docs](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Navigation).

Comment: If your page still refreshes after this, could you post an example of your Links that are causing a refresh? Thanks.

Comment: It still does't work. So I have added the req.url. It correctly detects the url when there is a page refresh. But when i try to push url like this `history.pushState({id: 'SOME ID'}, 'Title', 'about');` it doesn't work.

Comment: I am trying to navigate from `http://localhost:3000/` to `http://localhost:3000/about`

Comment: Why are you manually invoking `history.pushState` and not using the built in `Link` component or router transitions?

Comment: `router transitions` - This is what i am missing. Can you point me to a document with example or just write write up a small code to explain this. Thanks for the push !

Comment: Use `<Link to="" [, params={} query={}]>` to replicate an anchor link to a route, or use the router method `transitionTo`. https://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Link and https://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Navigation.

Comment: Thanks mate. This worked ! Can you please update your answer with the `<Link>` tag. I am sure it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

This might help Meteor users:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

export default class MenuItem extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <li>
                <Link to={this.props.link}>{this.props.page}</Link>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

Import Link from `react-router` and use `<Link />` to create your links will prevent the page from refreshing.

- `this.props.link` and `this.props.page` are your dynamic data.